# Trying to install Wagtail demo site with Docker and getting 'no such table: wagtailcore_site'

Tags: docker, installation, wagtail

When I run docker-compose up and then go the browser, I get the following:

OperationalError at /

no such table: wagtailcore_site

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:     4.1.8
Exception Type:     OperationalError
Exception Value:    no such table: wagtailcore_site

Exception Location:     /venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py, line 357, in execute
Raised during:  wagtail.views.serve
Python Executable:  /venv/bin/uwsgi
Python Version:     3.9.16
Python Path:

['.',
'',
'/code',
'/usr/local/lib/python39.zip',
'/usr/local/lib/python3.9',
'/usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
'/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages']

Server time:    Tue, 25 Apr 2023 09:15:32 +0000

Comment: Did the `docker compose run app /venv/bin/python manage.py load_initial_data` command complete successfully?

Comment: No. It's ending with the same operational error

Comment: My initial question referred to my efforts on Macbook Air. So I tried the same installation on my Linux Mint box - followed all the instructions for installing with Docker and guess what? The exact same operational error!!! no such table: wagtailcore_site

Comment: Confirming I'm seeing the same issue with the installation now - investigating.

Comment: Bug report now opened at https://github.com/wagtail/bakerydemo/issues/409

Comment: Thank you @gasman - I'm just a newbie and thought it was my stupidity!! BTW I got it working fine using a virtual environment on both Mac and Linux Mint 21